# Limiting repetation in Formik FormData

Tags: javascript, formik

It is rare that I send `FormData` via Formik, but when I do, it becomes very repetitive i.e.

```js
formData.append(k,v)
formData.append(k,v)
formData.append(k,v)
```

and I do this when there is only one or two file(s) to upload, I wish to remove the repetition which is present here.

I tried a couple of ways

```
  let formData = new FormData();
  Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => formData.append(key, values[key]));
```

and

```
  for (let key in values) {
    formData.append(key, values[key]);
  }
```

but those did not work with Formik. Is there any solution to it?

Comment: Can you share your code, so we can help to debug what makes it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

There is `obj-to-formdata`, which abstracts the repetition and handles nested objects:

https://github.com/therealparmesh/object-to-formdata

```
const data = {
    title: 'title',
    text: 'text',
    preview: {p_title:'p title', p_text: 'p text'}
};

const formData = objectToFormData(data);
```

It handles File objects too.

Comment: oh looks neat, let me try it